# How can I check if my host does not allow SSH access

Tags: java, mysql, ssh

I have tried everything to create an SSH connection to my remote MySQL database.

```
        String user = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        String remoteHost = "host";
        int localPort = 2022;
        int remotePort = 3306;
        Session session = null;

        //Try to forward ports
        try
        {
        //Create the JSCH object
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        //Get the session
        session = jsch.getSession(user, remoteHost);

        //Set the password
        session.setPassword(password);

        //To be able to connect to any host (this is just for testing!)
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        //Connect the session
        session.connect();

        //Set port forward
        session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, "127.0.0.1", remotePort);

        //Show message
        System.out.println("Waiting for connections…");

        //Exit on return
        InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
        in.readLine();
        }

        //Failed
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        //Message
        System.out.println("Failed to setup tunnel");

        //Stack trace
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Clean up
        finally
        {
        try{session.disconnect();} catch(Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace();}
        }
```

Yet I keep getting this error: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out

I don't understand why it is giving me that error because I believe I am using the right information. So my question is, how would I check my host's remote ip and how would I make sure they do allow SSH access?

UPDATE:

I am able to connect to the remote MySQL database through ssh -v user@host. However, in my code I am getting this error:

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:2022 cannot be bound.

I am using a mac, is the local port different in macs?

Comment: You should probably be specifying the ssh port (`int remotePort = 22;`); if that doesn't work, you'll need to ask your provider.

Comment: port `3306`  is used for mysql. What do you want to do with ssh?? only remote ssh or mysql connection over ssh??

Comment: Can you please post the statcktrace fo the exception? If your manual connection is working, including the forward of the MySQL port. Then your code should work as well. As there is nothing wrong so far.

Comment: The exception I am getting is:
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:2022 cannot be bound.

Comment: `local port 127.0.0.1:2022 cannot be bound` means the port `2022` is already used on your local machine. Maybe you have this session `ssh -v user@host -L 2022:127.0.0.1:3306` still open?

Comment: **1)** If you mean closing this session `ssh -v user@host -L 2022:127.0.0.1:3306`. Type `exit` and the remote shell will close. **2)** If you mean closing the application which is using port `2022` on your local machine. With `netstat` (have a look into `man netstat`, I don't now the concrete options on a Mac) you can identify the application listening on port `2022`. **3)** You could use another local port.

Answer (score 0):

Here few steps to isolate the origin of the problem. As it might be not related to your Java code.

1. try first a SSH connection from shell, to check if SSH is working in general
   `ssh -v user@host`
2. if this already fails -> ask the host administrator
3. if this succeeds try
   `ssh -v user@host -L 2022:127.0.0.1:3306`
   you should be now able to connect to MySql via local port `2022`
4. if this fails -> ask the host administrator
5. if this suceeds try to find the issue in your Java code

Some helpful links for SSH tunnel and MySql: [MySQL Remote Connectivity: SSH-Tunnel, HTTP-Tunnel](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?30,249779,249779)

Comment: So for -v user@host, it isn't needed to put the password? And for host do I type the ip of do I do the ip and the port?

Comment: @fontquest **1)** The password you have to entere manually in that case. **2)** In your posted code you also did not specify the port of the SSH server. So it will use the standard one. Which is `22`.

Comment: I mean through shell, do I need to enter my pasword? How

Comment: @fontquest Not sure if I understand. When you see `user@hosts's password:` in the shell you type the password and press the ENTER key. shell in this context means: a terminal console (e.g. bash) in Linux/OS X or the cmd shell in Windows.

Comment: I typed my user@hostsip, then I was asked to type a password. I did and then I got this: lodebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

Comment: @fontquest Then the most efficient way would be to ask the administrator of the remote host to assist yout with the SSH connection problem. As there as manyfold possiblities why it's not working like this. You could try with `-vvv` instead of `-v` to increase the debug output. But, as it seems you are not familar with SSH, it might not be of much help for you.

Comment: Thank you! I accessed it through shell, now I am just having problems with my code